# Crash with IllegalStateException: search must not be null when moving to the second activity to use a Searchview using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I have a very simple `MainActivity` which should move to a second activity when a button is clicked. The second activity uses a `Searchview` to search through a bunch of strings.

When I click on the button (in `MainActivity`) it crashes.

Any help really appreciated

**MainActvity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private val SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    
    /* THE GUTS OF IT */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d( "TAG","MainActivity 1- JEZ" )
            val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(intent, SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val gotthisInt = data?.getIntExtra("MY_KEY", 1) ?: 1
                Log.d("TAG", "What was received = $gotthisInt")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Debug - to be deleted -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDebug"
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
        android:text="DEBUG IT"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Searchbutton"
        android:layout_width="58dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textDebug"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SearchActivity.kt**

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
    private lateinit var listView: ListView
    private lateinit var emptyView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        Log.d("TAG", "OnCreate  Starts 101 MYDEBUG")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.search_main)
        title = "KotlinApp"

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
        emptyView = findViewById(R.id.emptyView)
        adapter = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.vegetables))

        listView.adapter = adapter

        listView.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { adapterView, _, i, _ ->
            Toast.makeText(this@SearchActivity, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        Log.d("TAG", "OnCreate 111 Ends MYDEBUG")

        listView.emptyView = emptyView
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        val search = menu.findItem(R.id.appSearchBar)

        Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu - 301 - Gets here MYDEBUG")
        val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView   /* Crashes here */
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu - 302 - Doesn't get here MYDEBUG")

        searchView.queryHint = "Search"
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

**search_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchActivity">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="No Results"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout
```

**Nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/appSearchBar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**Error Log**
…

```
2020-12-22 19:31:02.151 27250-27250/com.dbtest.vegtestaug2020 D/TAG: onCreateOptionsMenu - 301 - Gets here JEZ
2020-12-22 19:31:02.152 27250-27250/com.dbtest.vegtestaug2020 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-12-22 19:31:02.156 27250-27250/com.dbtest.vegtestaug2020 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dbtest.vegtestaug2020, PID: 27250
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: search must not be null
        at com.dbtest.VegNov2020d.SearchActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SearchActivity.kt:61)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4074)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3070)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1895)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2176)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:271)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-12-22 19:31:02.188 27250-27250/com.dbtest.vegtestaug2020 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27250 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem that you use `SearchView` from the old support library API; instead you need to replace it with androidx one

So, replace below in the nav_menu.xml

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

with

```
app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

Also make sure you import the right androidx `SearchView` class in `SearchActivity`

Comment: Many thanks…but sadly it still crashes at the same place. I’ve changed the nav_menu.xml to use androidx, and have confirmed it’s importing androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView. Should it be importing  kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.search_main.* please? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Winny .. thanks for the comment.. you can use this import `import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` .. I tested it and it works with me